# Logoff computer using java

Tags: java, windows, logging, logoff

How to use java to log off windows. It could be using some windows own exe through Runtime(),
or and other methods.It would be more efficient if you could provide some good alternative than using external programs like nircmd.exe .

When I use this code,

```
String shutdownCmd = "rundll32.exe shell32.dll,SHExitWindowsEx 0";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shutdownCmd);
```

I get

[image: ERROR MSG]

Comment: Well, running `C:\Windows\System32\logoff.exe` logs you off of Windows, so why don't you run that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this (`-l` for logoff here, `-r` for restart, etc.):

```
String shutdownCmd = "shutdown -l";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shutdownCmd);
```

or (`0` for logoff here):

```
String shutdownCmd = "rundll32.exe shell32.dll,SHExitWindowsEx 0";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shutdownCmd);
```

Comment: How to do hibernation?

Answer (score 2):

You can also make a simple .bat file if it's just a file you want.
Open notepad, type the code below, save as *all files, call it 'logoff.bat' or something and it should work.

```
shutdown -l
```

Comment: And you can also convert a .bat to and .exe if it's an .exe you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could call the `shutdown` executable from the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` method.  Check out this Q&A for details on that: [How do I shutdown - restart - logoff Windows via a bat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162304/how-do-i-shutdown-restart-logoff-windows-via-bat-file)