# How do you make a Console program that shuts down Windows?

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm new to Stack Overflow so this is my first question on. I'm trying to make a **console** application that shuts down instantly in **C#**. Currently this is **ALL** the code that i have in the project.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    static extern bool InitiateSystemShutdown(
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpMachinename,
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpMessage,
                Int32 dwTimeout,
                bool bForceAppsClosed,
                bool bRebootAfterShutdown);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {          
        InitiateSystemShutdown("localhost", null, 0, true, false);
    }
}
```

For some reason it only works every once in a while. And by that I mean I could click it 20 times and it wont do anything. But on some occasions it works on the first try, and shuts down the computer as expected. But this needs to be perfect. So I was wondering if there was any professionals (I'm kinda of a beginner) out there who could give me some advice/code. Am I missing something? Is something out of place? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to shut down what?

Comment: @VigneshKumar I'm guessing the system (Windows), according to the function call.

Comment: Does it has to be this way? I can show you how to close it using cmd.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162304/how-do-i-shutdown-restart-logoff-windows-via-bat-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

ProcessStartInfo shutdown = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown.exe", "-s");
    Process.Start(shutdown);
```

additional alternatives are available, just make a search or look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162304/how-do-i-shutdown-restart-logoff-windows-via-bat-file) or [here](http://blog.domdomsoft.com/2009/07/27/domdomsoft/manga-downloader/shutdown-computer-in-c/).