# batch - simple shutdown script

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-8, shutdown

I wanted to write a simple batch script to shutdown my own computer which will be used when I'm in bed watching a DVD or something.

**UPDATE: fixed the code, any other suggestions?**

```
setlocal
@echo off & break off
:input
set /p "minutes=Enter number of minutes to wait until shutdown: "
set "numcheck="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%minutes%") do set "numcheck=%%i"""
if defined numcheck (
    echo ERROR: Sorry "%minutes%" is not numeric, please try again & echo.
    goto input
)
if %minutes% gtr 315360000 (
    echo ERROR: Sorry your input is greater then 10 years, I can't handle that & echo.
    goto input
)
set /a "seconds=%minutes%*60"
shutdown.exe /s /f /t "%seconds%"
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo ERROR: Could not set shutdown, try again & echo.
    goto input
)
:abort
set /p "continue=Your computer is about to shutdown in %minutes% minutes, do you want to abort? (yes/no): "
if %continue% equ yes (
    echo Aborting...
    shutdown.exe /a
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo ERROR: Could not stop shutdown, try again & echo.
        goto abort
    )
    timeout.exe /t 5 /NOBREAK
    endlocal
    exit /b
) else (
    timeout.exe /t 10 /NOBREAK
    endlocal
    exit /b
)
```

Comment: Do you get an error, or why is it not working?

Comment: i fixed it myself 1 minute after posting here. lol, anyway i'll update the code above, maybe you guys have some other suggestions ;)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `&&` is used to check errorlevel.  `&` separates commands.

Comment: thx foxidrive, i updated the code

Answer (score 4):

The most common ways to use the [`shutdown`](https://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html) command are:

- `shutdown -s` — Shuts down.
- `shutdown -r` — Restarts.
- `shutdown -l` — Logs off.
- `shutdown -h` — Hibernates.

  **Note:** There is a common pitfall wherein users think `-h` means "help" (which it does for every other command-line program... except `shutdown.exe`, where it means "hibernate"). They then run `shutdown -h` and accidentally turn off their computers. Watch out for that.
- `shutdown -i` — "Interactive mode". Instead of performing an action, it displays a GUI dialog.
- `shutdown -a` — Aborts a previous shutdown command.

The commands above can be combined with these additional options:

- `-f` — Forces programs to exit. Prevents the shutdown process from getting stuck.
- `-t <seconds>` — Sets the time until shutdown. Use `-t 0` to shutdown immediately.
- `-c <message>` — Adds a shutdown message. The message will end up in the Event Log.
- `-y` — Forces a "yes" answer to all shutdown queries.

  **Note:** This option is not documented in any official documentation. It was discovered by [these StackOverflow users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071009/what-exactly-does-shutdown-y-do).

---

I want to make sure some other really good answers are also mentioned along with this one. Here they are in no particular order.

- [The `-f` option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162304/how-do-i-shutdown-restart-logoff-via-bat-file#162342) from [JosephStyons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/672/kogus)
- [Using `rundll32`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162304/how-do-i-shutdown-restart-logoff-via-bat-file#162398) from [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)
- [The Run box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162304/how-do-i-shutdown-restart-logoff-via-bat-file#162428)  from [Dean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14966/dean)
- [Remote shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162304/how-do-i-shutdown-restart-logoff-windows-via-bat-file#416830) from [Kip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18511/kip)

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown -s -t100
Save it with .bat extenstion
Shutsdown in 100 secx