# What exactly does "shutdown -y" do?

Tags: cmd, shutdown

I tried some random parameters after the `shutdown` command in PowerShell 2.0 when I stumbled upon `shutdown -y`. All it *seems* to do is log out the user.
if any other random letter is used (that isn't a valid parameter) nothing happens. For example: `shutdown -b`

My question is: Does `shutdown -y` do anything special?

I could not find any documentation about this.

Comment: maybe the command `shutdown /?`can help :D
This should contain all info about the command.

Comment: @Christian I tried that, but it doesn't state any info about `-y`

Comment: I don't know, where else you can find the info about it ... or it could be only an alias for `shutdown -l` ...

Comment: The documentation says "Used without parameters, shutdown will logoff the current user" so it seems like it's interpreting -y as if no parameter was passed.

Comment: @MarkWragg I also thought that might be the case, but other random (not documented) characters like `-b` or `-j` just end up displaying the same output as `-?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Windows 2000 documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/317371/how-to-use-the-remote-shutdown-tool-to-shut-down-and-restart-a-compute) states the following:

> /y: Use this switch to force a "yes" answer to all queries from the
>   computer.

So it looks like by using `-y` or `/y` with no other switches you are doing the default behaviour of shutdown.exe, which is to logoff the user while also forcing any confirm prompts to be acknowledged with yes.

Comment: This seems like the correct answer.

Comment: yeah. looks like Windows 2000 commands are still available in windows 7-10 :'D

Comment: @Christian The guys at Microsoft try try to keep things as compatible as possible so your scripts don't break with every new version. I wouldn't be surprised if /y has still the same behavior is simply ignored for sake of compatibility. Can somebody test that?

Answer (score 1):

`Shutdown` is not exactly a PowerShell command. It's the same `shutdown.exe` that also works in CMD.

Interestingly, the `-y` command is not mentioned in [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx). As *Mark Wragg* found out, it's used to force a "yes" answer for remote shutdown. So, if no other parameters are specified, the default action (logoff user) is executed.

Another question: Why were you trying random parameters? Follow the docu and you're less likely to encounter any unexpected behavior.

Comment: I wondered what powershell would reply when I entered something that's "definitely wrong" as parameter, so I entered `shutdown -yeet` and apparently that wasn't "definitely wrong"...

Comment: @Hulkerman What happens depends almost entirely on the command (or cmdlet, script, executable...). Except maybe when it's simply a syntax error like `shutdown <`.