# Bat file- If file exists then restart computer

Tags: batch-file, restart, delete-file

What would the contents of a bat file be if I want the following

If a file exists (file name and location)

Then delete the file and then restart the computer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Shutdown - Restart - Logoff Windows via bat file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162304/how-do-i-shutdown-restart-logoff-windows-via-bat-file). There are literally dozens of questions here about testing to see if a file exists and deleting it. It would appear you've made no effort to research doing this yourself first before posting. (The dupe I linked I found by looking at the **Related** list at the right of this very question without even having to search, and that list was shown to you before you posted the question.)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward -

```
@echo off
set FileToCheck=NAME_OF_THE_FILE_HERE
if not exist %FileToCheck% goto done
del %FileToCheck%
shutdown /r
:done
```

You could also use `set FileToCheck=%1` instead of hard-coding the filename in your batch file if you want to pass the filename to look for as a command line parameter,  i.e. (assuming your batch file is named `foo.bat`):

```
c:\>foo RemoveMeAndRebootIfIExist.txt
```