# shutdown PC after finishing a script

Tags: r, windows, shutdown

I'm runnig a script in R that takes many hours. I woud like that my PC automatically shutdown itself after finish my script. Is that possible? How can I do that using R? 
I've searched for packages and functions for that, but I couldn't find.
Thank you
P.S. My PC s running Windows 8.1

Comment: R can call commands using `?system` functions - maybe try something like those listed here: http://superuser.com/questions/674087/how-to-shut-down-a-windows-8-1-pro-computer-in-remote-session

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can call the cmd prompt directly from R

```
system('shutdown -s')
```

You can view other shutdown commands here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/162305/1362215.  This may be useful if you want to perform other tasks.

Comment: Executing system("shutdown") will show all available options for shutting your computer down from R, like rebooting, hibernating...