# NodeJs - can it reboot its host pc?

Tags: node.js

Have a nodejs - socketio application kiosk running windows 7 in kiosk mode(desktop).

Occasionally on boot a handshake doesn't occur between socketio and the client app also running on the same pc. There is a connection but it is immediately dropped. This happens randomly roughly 5% of the time on reboot

The only way I've been able to reliably get the handshake working is to manually reboot the pc.

I can see the nodejs trace showing the lost connection when the error occurs.
I was wondering is there was a way for nodejs to dynamically reboot its host pc (in this case running Windows 7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has the `shutdown` command: [How do I shutdown - restart - logoff Windows via a bat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162304/how-do-i-shutdown-restart-logoff-windows-via-a-bat-file)

You should be able to spawn an process to execute that.