# Exit cmd (or shutdown) after ffmpeg done

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg, shutdown

Is there a command to automatically close cmd (or shutdown the pc) after a `ffmpeg` command have been executed?

I'm using this command to download a video:

```
ffmpeg -i link.m3u8 -c copy video.mkv
```

And I want that cmd will close, or the pc will shutdown, after done downloading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want a batch file or a cmd line?

A batch file (which will shutdown after `ffmpeg` is complete):

```bat
@echo off

ffmpeg -i link.m3u8 -c copy video.mkv
shutdown /p
```

Or, if you want to exit:

```bat
@echo off

ffmpeg -i link.m3u8 -c copy video.mkv
exit /b
```

For cmd (exits after `ffmpeg` is complete):

```bat
ffmpeg -i link.m3u8 -c copy video.mkv & exit /b
```

Or, if you want to shutdown:

```bat
ffmpeg -i link.m3u8 -c copy video.mkv & shutdown /p
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a quick little batch file to do this:

```
start path\to\ffmpeg.exe -i link.m3u8 -c copy video.mkv
exit 
shutdown /s /f /t 0
```

Obviousy, `exit` is for exiting `cmd` and that sequence of `shutdown` and its associated flags will [turn off your PC immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162304/how-do-i-shutdown-restart-or-log-off-windows-via-a-bat-file) (if you're doing this, you don't really need to bother exiting `cmd` since it will do it anyway).  Save the above as something like `my_file.bat`, and then just type `path\to\your\my_file.bat` into the command prompt.